# How do I create RDS parameter groups from an arbitrary number of input parameters?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a four different environments:

- dev
- sit
- uat
- prod

The parameter group values differ for each environment. Below value will go in variable file for each environment.

Below are the parameters of an example AWS RDS parameter group. In other environments, there may be more or less parameters:

```
parameter {
  name = "character_set_client"
  value = "utf8mb4"
}

parameter {
  name = "character_set_connection"
  value = "utf8mb4"
}

parameter {
  name = "character_set_server"
  value = "utf8mb4"
}

parameter {
  name = "log_bin_trust_function_creators"
  value = "1"
}
```

I'm curious how to represent this in variables and how to write the resources to use those variables to make RDS Parameter Groups with an arbitrary number of parameters.

How do I create RDS parameter groups from an arbitrary number of input parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a dynamic block:

```
dynamic "parameter" {
    for_each = var.parameters
    content {
      name         = parameter.value.name
      value        = parameter.value.value
    }
  }
```

The variable can be a list of maps:

```
variable "parameters" {
  type        = list(map(string))
  default     = []
}
```

`terraform.tfvars`:

```
parameters = [ 
  {
  name = "character_set_connection"
  value = "utf8mb4"
  },
  {
  name = "character_set_server"
  value = "utf8mb4"
  },
  {
  name = "log_bin_trust_function_creators"
  value = "1"
  }
]
```

Comment: For terraform 0.12 ?

Comment: After plan ,   I got it as   parameter {
          + apply_method = "immediate"
          + name         = "character_set_server"
          + value        = "utf8mb4"
        }

Comment: The apply_method is optional with "immediate" (default), or "pending-reboot". You can add it to the parameters if you like and use the following syntax to see if it is available or set it to null if not: `apply_method = lookup(parameters.apply_method, "apply_method", null)`